# curvilinear coordinates - meaning of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvilinear-coordinates

I am taking a course in mathematics for physicists and in one of the lectures my professor has written the following paragraph:

"given the transformation $q1 = q1(x,y,z)$, $q2 = q2(x,y,z)$, $q3 = q3(x,y,z)$ and $x = x(q1,q2,q3)$, $y = y(q1,q2,q3)$, $z = z(q1,q2,q3)$, we can use $(q1,q2,q3)$ as general coordinates that span $\mathbb R^3$: $\vec r (q1,q2,q3): \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$"

What is the meaning of $\vec r (q1,q2,q3): \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$?
could you give an example?

I found an example in older lecture notes of another professor, which was using spherical coordinates $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$ for $(q1,q2,q3)$ and cartesian coordinates:

$\vec r (\rho,\theta,\phi): \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 ; \vec r (\rho,\theta,\phi) = ( \rho sin(\theta)cos(\phi),\rho sin(\theta)sin(\phi),\rho cos(\theta))$. is it correct?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your professor is assuming
$$
\overrightarrow{r} =
\begin{bmatrix}
x(q_1, q_2, q_3)\\
y(q_1, q_2, q_3)\\
z(q_1, q_2, q_3)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $\overrightarrow{r}$ defines a bijection $\overrightarrow{r} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ which is diffeomorphic if the functions $x, y, z : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $q_1, q_2, q_3 : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth. Functions like these are often called *transformations*, or *coordinate change* by physicists.

As example you can take
$$
\overrightarrow{r} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 q_2 + q_1\\
q_3^3\\
q_1 - q_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This can be easily checked to be bijective and smooth, but not diffeomorphic! Moreover notice that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not special at all: the same argument can be repeated in any dimension.

The idea behind spherical coordinates is the same, however in this case the function
$$\overrightarrow{r}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho(q_1, q_2, q_3)\\
\theta(q_1, q_2, q_3)\\
\phi(q_1, q_2, q_3)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not diffeomorphic anymore, so spherical coordinates are, in some way, "singular". As excercise you could think about this fact and check points where things go wrong.

Comment: thank you, I guess I got confused by Chatgpt's answer and lack of details in the old lecture notes. could you recommend resources that discuss differential geometry and subjects related to my question (for mathematicians, not necessarily for physicists).

Comment: Never trust chatGPT's answers about mathematics (but also in general), it's just a software trained to assemble pieces of text in a "realistic way".
As reference you could find something on Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*, or in Arnold's *Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics*